# MySQL JDBC returning 0 results

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

It seems a very basic question but I couldn't find any resolution for it.
I have following code with me:

```
package com.test.db.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCConnect
{
private Connection conn = null;
private final String uname = "root";
private final String passwd = "test@123";
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/TrainDB";
private final String className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public void initConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if(this.conn == null || this.conn.isClosed())
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName (className).newInstance ();
                this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, passwd);
                System.out.println("database connection established.");
            }
            catch(SQLException sqe)
            {
                sqe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InstantiationException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return this.conn;
}

public void disconnect()
{
    if (conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close ();
                System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
        }

}

public void insertData(String sql)
{
    PreparedStatement s;
    try
    {

        if(conn == null || conn.isClosed())
        {
            initConnection();
        }
        s = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        int count = s.executeUpdate ();
        s.close ();
        System.out.println (count + " rows were inserted");
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close ();
                System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
            }
            catch (Exception se) { /* ignore close errors */ }
        }
    }

}

public ResultSet query(String sql)
{
    Statement s = null;
    try
    {
        if(this.conn == null || this.conn.isClosed())
        {
            initConnection();
        }

                    s = conn.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
        System.out.println("lets see " + rs.getFetchSize());
        return rs;
    }
    catch(SQLException sq)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in query");
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

I am using JDBCConnect in a different class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class traininfo
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JDBCConnect jdbcConn = new JDBCConnect();

    String sql = "SELECT id FROM testtable";
    ResultSet rs = jdbcConn.query(sql);
    try {
        System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(rs != null)
    {
        try
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqe)
        {

        }
    }
    jdbcConn.disconnect();
}
}
```

I am not using concurrent calls for insertion and reads. If I use the same query in mysql-workbench (client), I am getting proper results but using the mentioned code, I am getting

```
database connection established.
lets see 0
0
Database connection terminated
```

Please suggest me what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe id isn't a String ? Try rs.getInt("id") or some such.

Comment: no luck.. :-(
infact, System.out.println("lets see " + rs.getFetchSize()); returnign 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's because you're closing `Statement` before you are using it's `ResultSet`. It's strange that it doesn't throw an exception, but this is not correct anyway.

As per [Statement.close method JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29):

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

I suggest to use some kind of callback to retrieve results from `ResultSet` before it's closed e.g.:

```
public <T> T query(String sql, IResultSetHandler<T> resultSetHandler ) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        final ResultSet rs = connection.executeQuery(sql);
        final T result = resultSetHandler.handle(rs);
        return result;
    } finally {
        if(statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
    }
}

public interface IResultSetHandler<T> {
    T handle(ResultSet rs);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDBCConnect jdbcConn = new JDBCConnect();
    List<String> ids = jdbcConn.query(sql, new IResultSetHandler<List<String>>() {
        public List<String> handle(ResultSet rs) {
            List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                ids.add(rs.getString("id"));
            }
            return ids;
        }
    });
}
```

Or to use commons apache dbutils library which does exactly the same.

Comment: i am using s.close() in finally, even if i remove that the result is the same.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Comment: Agreed - as you close the statement before returning the resultset, you won't ever have anything in the result set, and as as per the other answer, it is perfectly reasonble for getFetchSize to return 0 even if you matched hundreds of rows.

Comment: yeah, it's working perfectly fine. But out of curiosity, why the simplest piece of code was not working? I mean, the rs.next() was not going in the while loop.

Comment: Don't know either ... Personally I've never used `statement.executeQuery` and then `statement.getResultSet()`. I used it like the following: `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(...)`, maybe that's the problem, though it's strange

Answer (score 2):

`ResultSet.getFetchSize()` lets you know the *maximum* number of rows that the connection will fetch at once. You can set it with `ResultSet.setFetchSize(int)`. See also [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize%28int%29). It does not tell you how many rows in total you will get. If the fetch size is left to zero, JDBC decides on its own.

Other than that, refer to Yura's answer which addresses the core of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you never call InsertRows, as it never shows that 'X rows were inserted'

Comment: tables were not created through jdbc.